# How to get the oidc authtication url in my react frontend using django rest framwork

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, openid-connect

I am trying to use mozilla-django-oidc package to implement SSO in my drf app. But I'm having a problem getting the authentication URL in my React frontend. In the docs, they show how it can be used with a non rest django app where the views are returned by django, but that's not the case in my app. What do I set as the authentication URL for the OIDC in my react SSO link???

This is the example in the docs, but as you can see I won't have the luxury of django templating and so it confuses me how I am supposed to specify the URL in my React frontend.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <p>Current user: {{ user.email }}</p>
  <form action="{% url 'oidc_logout' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="logout">
  </form>
{% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'oidc_authentication_init' %}">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

What I have done is while testing out the OIDC implementation my coworker has made work using regular django copied what the SSO link points to and used that in my React frontend pointing to my drf backend.

Like so:

```
http://localhost:8000/oidc/authenticate/
```

But after I do that, I get a page not found error. Instead of the sign on page.

I'm unsure how to add the correct authentication URL in React, and unsure how to redirect back to react after authentication

UPDATE

Ok so it seems just copying the link might've actually worked but my problem still persit that after auth the user then redirects to localhost:8000/ which is not a route and I need it to redirect to my frontend  localhost:3000

Comment: Are you using create react app or similar? Or something like vite/webpack dev server. Has this been configured to proxy to the underlying web server? What you did (copy the URL from known install) is not unreasonable. Your bigger issue is its not there anyway. It might be worth sharing your proxy config.

Comment: I am using create react app, but I haven't set up any kind of proxy, how would I do that? @AdamThomas

Comment: See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/. I know the thing your proxying is really a page and not an API request, but i think its all the same in regards to the config.